# Partial derivative of $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$

Tags: analysis

I know that this is a basic question, but for some reason I got confused and I don't have much time for this (I have to present this tomorrow) so I might as well just ask it.

If we are given a function $f(x,y)$ such that we have its partial derivatives, and then given the function $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$, what are the partial derivatives of $g$ with respect to $x$ and $y$. I considered taking $g(x,y)=f(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ where $u(x,y)=y$ and $v(x,y)=x$, and then consider $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ but have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ evaluated at $(u(x,y),v(x,y))$.

However, this seems like a wrong way of thought, and so I hope someone might clear this out.

The example I have is $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y+3y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ where the partial derivatives are to be evaluated at $(1,0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: ${{\partial g}\over {\partial x}}(u,v)=lim_{h\rightarrow 0
} {{g(u+h,v)-g(u,v)}\over h}={{f(v,u+h)-f(v,u)}\over h}={{\partial f}\over {\partial y}}(v,u)$